# Equivalent UTL_RAW.BIT_OR in JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql, named-query

I'm trying to make a namedquery with a result DTO where there is a field that I have to calculate using that function. Is there any equivalent?

```
SELECT new BitsDTO( 
UTL_RAW.BIT_OR(b.bitsA, b.bitsB) as bitsCalculated)
FROM Bits b
where b.id = ?;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show to what java type your property `b.bitsA` is mapped?

Comment: byte[] bitsA;
byte[] bitsB;

Comment: You can try to register `UTL_RAW.BIT_OR` function in your custom hibernate dialect that will extend some standard hibernate dialect. As for how function can be registered, see for example [this](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL81Dialect.java#L120). And then you can use it in jpql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a database function in JPQL you can do it like this

```
SELECT new BitsDTO(
    function("UTL_RAW.BIT_OR", b.bitsA, b.bitsB)
)
FROM Bits b
where b.id = ?
```

That way you can call any database function. The first argument is the function name.

Comment: Do you get an error message? And how does the generated SQL look like?

Answer (score 0):

@Simon Martinelli was almost right. Calling database functions from a top-level select clause item requires casting so that Hibernate knows how to read the value from JDBC like this: `select new BitsDTO(cast(function('UTL_RAW.BIT_OR', b.bitsA, b.bitsB) as java.lang.String) ...`

The alternative to this is that you register the function as `SQLFunction` in your dialect and provide a proper return type for it. Then you can use is like you had in your original question.